# Mono Shared Runtime is enabled

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to create archive for Xamarin Android application created in Visual studio 2017. I always get an error "Shared mono runtime is enabled in your project" but I actually it is disabled and Release mode is selected but still not working.

Disabled Shared runtime and set on Release mode

Comment: If what you are saying is true, this sounds like a bug. You can open a free email support case to report it. You can open a free Xamarin support case here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=classiccommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=16068&forceorigin=esmc&ccsid=636645150473349054

Answer (score 1):

It's a old question but my answer may help someone.
In your Android project file *.csproj set false to AndroidUseSharedRuntime.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
   ...
   <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols> 
   <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
   ...
```